# Configuração do .htaccess não está funcionando

Tags: php

Olá, estou tentando configurar o htaccess, mas não está funcionando.O arquivo htaccess é este

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ /desenvolvimento/uniseries/site/
RewriteRule ^index$ /desenvolvimento/uniseries/site/index.php
RewriteRule ^livros$ /desenvolvimento/uniseries/site/livros.php
RewriteRule ^humor$ /desenvolvimento/uniseries/site/humor.php
RewriteRule ^diversos$ /desenvolvimento/uniseries/site/diversos.php
RewriteRule ^contato$ /desenvolvimento/uniseries/site/contato.php
RewriteRule ^series$ /desenvolvimento/uniseries/site/series.php
RewriteRule ^filmes$ /desenvolvimento/uniseries/site/filmes.php
RewriteRule ^entrevistas$ /desenvolvimento/uniseries/site/entrevistas.php
```

Falta algo para configurar? Lembrando que utilizo diversas pastas, essa seria do site, o admin não tem, somente esta pagina, eu sei que funciona isto, pois contratei uma programadora para fazer para mim, só que em outros projetos não estou conseguindo configurar. Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Qual é a pasta raiz do site? Por exemplo: http:/localhost/ ou http:/localhost/seu_site/

Comment: Já verificou se mod_rewrite do apache está habilitado?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma abaixo, removendo a / do começo, caso seu site não esteja na raiz, pois quando ser coloca a / no começo se refere a raiz do site, assim por exempo:

> http://localhost**/desenvolvimento/uniseries/site/**

E quando não se coloca ela, se refere a url relativa levando em conta a pasta onde está localizado o .htaccess:

> http://localhost/seu_site/**desenvolvimento/uniseries/site/**

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ desenvolvimento/uniseries/site/
RewriteRule ^index$ desenvolvimento/uniseries/site/index.php
RewriteRule ^livros$ desenvolvimento/uniseries/site/livros.php
RewriteRule ^humor$ desenvolvimento/uniseries/site/humor.php
RewriteRule ^diversos$ desenvolvimento/uniseries/site/diversos.php
RewriteRule ^contato$ desenvolvimento/uniseries/site/contato.php
RewriteRule ^series$ desenvolvimento/uniseries/site/series.php
RewriteRule ^filmes$ desenvolvimento/uniseries/site/filmes.php
RewriteRule ^entrevistas$ desenvolvimento/uniseries/site/entrevistas.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Tem uma série de fatores que devem ser considerados, mas experimente assim para ver se irá funcionar:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ desenvolvimento/uniseries/site/$1.php [QSA,L]
```